# How to get accessToken for firebase 3 using javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I need to make a shallow rest call using javascript with firebases REST Api, in the past version I needed to pass the access token like this:

```
    var authKey = ref.getAuth().token;
    var s = firebaseUrl + '/.json?shallow=true&auth=' + authKey;
    $http.get(s)
```

How do I do this now with firebase 3?

Comment: just to clarify, this is asking about the firebase jwt token and not the auth provider's access token. The firebase jwt token is used for firebase authentications and the auth provider's access token is used for provider authentication and accessing the provider's apis (e.g. drive API for google)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(u, p).then(function(result){

    result.getToken().then(function(token){
        $rootScope.userLoginToken = token;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

The access token is no longer available in the authData when you're using version 3.x of the SDK. But you can get is when the user gets authenticated with.

```
var auth = firebase.auth();

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
  var accessToken = result.credential.accessToken;
});
```

For this and a lot more information that is relevant when migrating your web app, see the [upgrade guide for web apps](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-web#get_the_access_token_numbered) (where I copied the code from).

Comment: Frank I can't seem to get result.credential using firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(), do I need to use another method? I'm justing using email/password auth method

Comment: There is no access token when you're using email and password. It sounds like you might be looking for @stradosphere's answer.

Comment: Isn't there a limitation now with `credential.accessToken` being exposed only during the login flow? If the user is already authenticated, the login routine never runs while the app uses saved auth data.