# [Firebase-OAuth]: How to access GitHub credentials/access token for returning customers

Tags: firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

How to access tokens for Firebase Login with OAuth for an existing session?

I can access the accessToken as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38004400/2743101 during login with a popup.

Is there a native way of accessing it, when I have a returning **already logged-in** user, or do I have to persist the token myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase Authentication only persists the credentials of the user for itself. It does not persist their credentials of the OAuth provider. If you want to re-use those across app restarts, you'll indeed have to persist them yourself.